# How to extract string from JSON object in protractor

Tags: json, automation, protractor, webstorm, web-api-testing

I am not able to extract string from JSON object in protractor in webstorm. I want value of statusCode i.e :200, The code I've tried for this mentioned below...

CODE IS :

```
console.log('body is :' + JSON.stringify(body));

var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(response);

console.log('---------response is: '+ jsonResponse);

var statusResponse = jsonResponse.getString("statusCode");

console.log('---- statusResponse is :'+ statusResponse.toString());
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
body is :{"oBody":{"payLoad":{"sLoginId":"HDB_TW_DSA@softcell.com","iInstId":4019,"sFirstName":"PRIYANKA","sLastName":"MADGUNDI","sEmail":"priyanka@softcell.com","sEmpId":"HDB18458","sMobile":"8237276692","bActive":true,"aRoles":["DSA"],"aDealers":[{"id":"TW423684019","iInstId":4019,"iDlrId":"42368","sDlrName":"GODSPEED MOTORCYCLE PVT LTD","iBranchId":1278,"sBranchName":"HYDERABAD-SF","sProduct":"TW","bActive":true},{"oStatus":{"iStatus":200,"sStatus":"OK"}}
```

---------response is:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":{"oBody":{"payLoad":{"sLoginId":"HDB_TW_DSA@softcell.com","iInstId":4019,"sFirstName":"PRIYANKA","sLastName":"MADGUNDI","sEmail":"priyanka@softcell.com","sEmpId":"HDB18458","sMobile":"8237276692","bActive":true,"aRoles":["DSA"],"aDealers","path":"/gonogo-api/atm/login-web-v3","href":"https://ssg.serviceurl.in/login-web-v3"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Postman-Token":"7aad048f-f8ad-4765-a0b8-be3b3a485ab6","cache-control":"no-cache","Content-Type":"application/json","accept":"application/json","content-length":380}}}
```

Comment: you need to JSON.parse() the response

Comment: hello @JeremyKahan
JSON.parse is not working.. 
getting output is :- response[object object]

Comment: the response is not valid json. Reasons: "adealers" should be followed by a colon. Perhaps relatedly https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ thinks it is short a brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below option

```
var res= JSON.parse(response);
console.log(res[0].statusCode);
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

So it appears what jsonResponse is giving you from the stringifying is not recognized as perfect json by json parse. So you can do the parsing yourself by finding where it says "statusCode:", taking the response string from a space beyond that for as long as statusCode could be and then some (8 characters seemed plenty to me), then taking only up to the comma. I assumed you want the code as a number, not a string, so I converted it.

```
var temp =jsonResponse.search('"statusCode":')+'"statusCode":'.length;
var temp2 = jsonResponse.slice(temp,temp+8);
var status = parseInt(temp2.slice(0,temp2.search(',')),10);
```